# How to improve this question?

Tags: support, specific-question

[Difference between oxo and formyl](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117065/difference-between-oxo-and-formyl)

This question was downvoted. Someone said Oxo is only used for ketone in the comment. I did some research to disprove that and shared this [link](https://the-educational-blog.quora.com/IUPAC-nomenclature-for-organic-compounds-Part-VI-Aldehydes-and-ketones) in the comments.

It is a Quora blog written by "Kurt Van den Broeck".

> ALDEHYDES:
>
> If they get priority in the name they get the suffix ‘al’ or ‘carbaldehyde’
> As substituent prefixes ‘oxo’ and ‘formyl’ are used. The prefix ‘formyl’ is used in preferred IUPAC names, except for a -CHO group at the end of an acyclic chain.

And it also answers my original question.
I thought of answering my own question by quoting from the link but he did not provide any source for his claim, so I choose not to answer my own question as it also may get downvotes. Is there any way to improve this question?

Comment: Well, if your question on main looked like this one, i.e. proper punctuation and capitalisation, length, citation with link...

Comment: @Mithoron I fixed the grammar. I am not a native english speaker.  Also added the link. What do you mean by length??

Comment: That the question body shouldn't be so short? Man, I understand that some have it harder, but considering your other meta posts, this seems to be getting embarrassing. Guys were even making fun of this "easter" in chat. Hmm, that may be a good idea - go to chat before asking a question of dubious quality and ask about it. I'm not sure which room would be best, but there are some newer ones where beginners help each other.